# Vue.js. Render of different kinds of child components according to a list of conditions

Tags: vue.js, itemrenderer

I'm new to not OOP, and VUE.JS especially.

I have a list of conditions, according to them I should show on the page several different kinds of components.

How can I render, for example, 2 TextInput components (or 3.. 10) dynamically and read the entered text in parent after clicking a button?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any code, so I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do.

If you want to display multiple components, just use `v-for` and specify conditions in `v-if`, which will detemine whether this particular component will be rendered:

```html
<input 
  v-for="input in inputs" 
  v-if="input.show"
  v-model="input.model"
  :placeholder="input.label" 
  type="text"
>

<button @click="handleButtonClick()">Button text</button>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  inputs: [
    { 
      label: 'input 1', 
      model: '',
      show: true
    },
    { 
      label: 'input 2', 
      model: '',
      show: true
    }
  ]
}),
methods: {
  handleButtonClick () {
    console.log(this.inputs)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. You've  helped me a lot!

Comment: @Sergey glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the type of component you need to display you can use [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

In a nutshell this defers the type of component used at runtime based on a value.

Let's assume you have 2 different type of components

- TextComponent
- ImageComponent

You can have a list of items

```
data () {
 return {
   items: [
     {
      id: 1,
      val: 'something',
      type: 'TextComponent'
     },
     {
      id: 2,
      val: 'something',
      type: 'ImageComponent'
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Now you can iterate over the list and display the component based on `type`

```
<component v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :is="item.type" v-model="item.value />
```

If `type` is not the exact name of the component, you can translate it inside the `:is` condition. Something like this.

```
:is="getComponentFromTag(item.type)"
```

And then write the conversion method

```
methods: {
 getComponentFromTag (tag) {
   switch (tag) {
     case 'text':
       return 'TextComponent'
     case 'img':
       return 'ImageComponent'
   }
 }
}
```

For the example above I'm assuming that `items` look like this:

```
items: [
     {
      id: 1,
      val: 'something',
      type: 'text'
     },
     {
      id: 2,
      val: 'something',
      type: 'img'
     }
   ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. You've  helped me a lot!